# How do I add another boot entry into grub2?

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, dual-boot

So I recently switched from Ubuntu to Manjaro but I lost my bootloader. Now I don't have an entry for Windows 7 anymore.

Linux and the bootloader are installed on sdb but windows lives on sda.

I can't find any information on how I would add /dev/sda to the bootoptions, most guides seem to suggest adding `/boot/grub/menu.lst` which I do not have.

Currently I switch from windows to linux and back, by changing the bootorder in the bios which is absolutely annoying.

Comment: Have you tried `update grub`? See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/400886/how-can-i-add-a-new-operating-system-boot-entry-to-the-grub2-menu

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Manjaro Wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Restore_the_GRUB_Bootloader) entry on bootloader configuration:

To deal with windows partitions, you will need to install the `mtools` and `os-prober` utilities:

```
pacman -S mtools os-prober
```

Then run the grub auto-update utility, which will now be able to access your windows partition

```
update-grub
```

Note: The config file `/boot/grub/menu.lst` is used by the old grub, not grub2. It has been replaced by `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, which is automatically generated by `update-grub` and should not be manually edited. Instead, edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and re-run the updater.

Comment: I already installed `mtools os-prober` and ran update-grub, it didn't help. And I don't see anything relevant in `/etc/default/grub` that I could change.

Comment: I have the same issue, tried mtools os-prober and update-grub, windows is not showing up.

Comment: Could you please post the results from the [Boot Info Script?](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript)

Comment: This worked for me! I have UEFI enabled and I had to convert the disk containing Windows 10 to GPT using mbr2gpt tool. Finally, I followed the steps mentioned above.

Comment: grub-mkconfig should be used.

Though if you look at the troubleshooting down at the wiki page, you can see they left a mention of update-grub....